# Tracking Plugin Conflicts WordPress (CiviCRM / Events Manager)

Tags: wordpress, civicrm

I am on WordPress 5.3.2 and I'm using CiviCRM, which is working appropriately.

However, I've tried to install Events Manager and when I do the event registration and contribution pages for CiviCRM stop displaying and direct to the CiviCRM homepage.

There is clearly a conflict, but it's non-error-causing and I'm not sure where to start with debugging.

It's not a path conflict as they're both on totally different paths with different permalink structures.

Where do I start?

Comment: You start by reaching out to the developers of the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've been digging around and here's the issue:

Events Manager Pro applies its own permalinks which override system defaults and other plugin settings.

The Events Manager Pro defaults have no leading slash, i.e., 'events/' rather than '/events/'

By adding the leading slash, everything works.